# get all indexes of all occurances of a substring in a string

Tags: c

i searched online everywhere but i was unable to find a solution that i could implement in my code, i have some limiting factors to take in accounts, the biggest one is: **i cannot use pointers to do this**, second one is that **i cannot edit before the comment**

what i have to do is look for the `SEC_B` sequence in the `adn1` string then save the position of it into a int array to then print it something like this:

```
Found sequence GTC in:  20 62 69 159 167 196
```

*and yes i did count them manually*

i have to do the same with the other sequences, but that doesn't matter as long is i can get it working with one, i can then make it work with all the others

so this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SECUENCIA0 "TGGCGTTTGCAGATTACTGCGTCCCTCACAAGGGTGTGAA"
#define SECUENCIA1 "GCTGTGCATTCGCGGCACAAGAGTCCCGGGTCCCTGTAGC"
#define SECUENCIA2 "TTCACCATCCTGTTGTACCTATCAAACCTACCTACAGCTT"
#define SECUENCIA3 "AGTGAAGGATTATGCGATTGGCGAGCATAGTACCGGCCCG"
#define SECUENCIA4 "TCACACCGTCTCATTGGTGGCCGACCTTGGAACTCCGTCA"
#define SEC_B "GTC"
#define SEC_D "GAT"
#define SEC_K "GT"

int main()
{
    char adn1[201];
    adn1[0]='\0';
    strcat(adn1,SECUENCIA0);
    strcat(adn1,SECUENCIA1);
    strcat(adn1,SECUENCIA2);
    strcat(adn1,SECUENCIA3);
    strcat(adn1,SECUENCIA4);
    //edit from here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions):  Make a genuine attempt yourself, show the code, ask a specific question.

Comment: i'll keep it in mind next time, honestly i would have posted my attempt but it was kinda really bad, and totally didn't do anything of what i was trying to do

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_indices_substr(const char *str, const char *substr)
{
    char *pstr;

    printf("Indices: { ");
    for (pstr = (char *)str; (pstr = strstr(pstr, substr)) != NULL; pstr = &pstr[1])
        printf("%lu, ", (uintptr_t)pstr - (uintptr_t)str);
    printf("}\n");
}
```

Basically, the function `strstr` returns a pointer to the first occurrence of 'substr' in 'str' or NULL if no occurrence was found. We can use this pointer in a for loop, and the index will be `pstr` - `str`, as you can see in the function above. Example:

```c
int main()
{
    const char my_string[] = "ABCDABCD";
    print_indices_substr(my_string, "ABCD");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Indices: { 0, 4, }
```

Comment: this would work great, if i could use pointers, i specified in my question that i could NOT use pointer, however, another user that has posted before then deleted the answer (name is zazz) gave me a partial solution to which i managed to come up with my own solution to both counting occurances and storing the indexes of the substring it finds, i'll post the answer right now

Comment: What do you mean you can't use pointers? A string itself is a pointer (const char *). If it wasn't like this, you'd do the exact same think, except instead of using `strstr` you'd do the comparison yourself, still using a pointer to know where in the string you're at.

Comment: we are using arrays of characters \0 terminated instead of const char * look at the solution i just posted, honestly if i could use strings as const char * it would have made my life much easier

Comment: A char[] is just a pointer to a buffer with defined size, doesn't matter. Also, what's the point of 'no explicit pointers'? The function `strstr` takes two pointers as parameters, and it returns a pointer. If you copy my function into another file, you can call it and say it doesn't use any explicit pointers as well. Just because you didn't type them, doesn't mean they aren't there. Is your '*' key broken or something?

Comment: hey those are the limitations the gave me, can''t really do much about it, if it was for me, i'd use your solution, they explicitly say in the pdf that there cannot be any * pointer definition

Comment: If you've been told to do it this way and there's nothing you can do about, it's fine. Technically, you can replace all pointers with `uintptr_t`s, they are unsigned integers with enough size to fit a pointer, which would comply with the limitations. I don't think not allowing the use of pointers has any use at all, but you already sorted things out, so it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

this solution doesn't involve any explicit pointers (no * anywhere) and doesn't edit the line above the comment, i managed to come up with this solution thanks to the answer of zazz (which he deleted for some reson), here's how i've done it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SECUENCIA0 "TGGCGTTTGCAGATTACTGCGTCCCTCACAAGGGTGTGAA"
#define SECUENCIA1 "GCTGTGCATTCGCGGCACAAGAGTCCCGGGTCCCTGTAGC"
#define SECUENCIA2 "TTCACCATCCTGTTGTACCTATCAAACCTACCTACAGCTT"
#define SECUENCIA3 "AGTGAAGGATTATGCGATTGGCGAGCATAGTACCGGCCCG"
#define SECUENCIA4 "TCACACCGTCTCATTGGTGGCCGACCTTGGAACTCCGTCA"
#define SEC_B "GTC"
#define SEC_D "GAT"
#define SEC_K "GT"

int main()
{
    char adn1[201];
    adn1[0]='\0';
    strcat(adn1,SECUENCIA0);
    strcat(adn1,SECUENCIA1);
    strcat(adn1,SECUENCIA2);
    strcat(adn1,SECUENCIA3);
    strcat(adn1,SECUENCIA4);
    //edit below here
    printf("---- Búsqueda de secuencias B, D y K dentro del adn1 ------\n");
    int PosicionesB[20];
    int bs = 0;
    int i, l1, l2;
    l1 = strlen(adn1);
    l2 = strlen(SEC_B);
    for(i = 0; i < l1 - l2 + 1; i++) {
        if(strstr(adn1 + i, SEC_B) == adn1 + i) {
            PosicionesB[bs] = i;
            bs++;
            i = i + l2 -1;
        }
    }
    printf("Found sequence GTC in:");
    for(int i = 0; i < bs;i++){
       printf("  %d",PosicionesB[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't involve pointers, then what does `strstr` return?

Comment: doesn't involve any **explicit** pointers, basically if it's pointer as a return, it's fine, but i cannot define any pointers myself, so no variables with *